# how to pass parameters on resolve time in autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I write following register type in autofac:

```
 builder.RegisterType<NoteBookContext>()
        .As<DbContext>()
        .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<DbContext>("connectionstring"));
```

In fact I write this code for injecting NoteBookContext with a connectionstring parameter. (ie : `new NoteBookContext(string connectionstring)`)

Now , How can I Pass value of parameter at runtime?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `WithParameter` method has a overload that accept delegate for dynamic instanciation.

The first argument is a predicate selecting the parameter to set whereas the second is the argument value provider :

```
builder.RegisterType<NoteBookContext>()
       .As<DbContext>()
       .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "connectionstring", 
                      (pi, c) => c.Resolve<IConnectionStringProvider>().ConnectionString);
```

See [Passing Parameters to Register](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html) from *Autofac* documentation for more detail.

Comment: Above code not working for me. Did I missed anything? Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61677516/autofac-resolve-constructor-parameters-not-working

Comment: This can work at resolve time but is not so good as `new NamedParameter(...)`

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass the connection string value while **resolving**, we first need to pass the delegate of the constructor into the `Register` method, and then pass the value of connection string with the `NamedParameter` into the `Resolve` method.

For example:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Register((pi, c) => new NoteBookContext(pi.Named<string>("connectionstring")))
            .As<DbContext>();
```

Now, on resolve time, we can assign to the resolved `DBContext` the `conncetionstring` value of `Consts.MyConnectionString`:

```
IContainer container = builder.Build();

NoteBookContext noteBookContext = container.Resolve<DbContext>(
    new NamedParameter(
        "connectionstring", Consts.MyConnectionString
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to do a lot/anything special if you are just passing in something quick, for me i was able to just pass in an instance of what i wanted to get injected.

```
container.Resolve<IFoo>(new List<Parameter>{ new TypedParameter(something.GetType(), something)});
```

Note: I know what i passed in was not registered with the container.