# Autofac ResolvedParameter/ComponentContext not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, dbcontext

I am using `asp.net core` along with `Entity Framework Core`. My scenario here is, I want to change the connection string at runtime based on `HttpContext` query string value.

I am trying to pass `ResolvedParameter` with `Reflection components` as [documented](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html#parameters-with-reflection-components). But, It is not getting registered when I resolve this. Here below, I have attached my code snippet.

**Autofac Registration class:**

```
public class DependencyRegistrar : IDependencyRegistrar
{
    public virtual void Register(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType(typeof(DbContextOptionsFactory))
            .As(typeof(IDbContextOptionsFactory))
            .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<AppDbContext>()
            .As(typeof(IDbContext))
            .WithParameter(
                new ResolvedParameter(
                    (pi, cc) => pi.Name == "options",
                    (pi, cc) => cc.Resolve<IDbContextOptionsFactory>().Get()));

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
            .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
            .SingleInstance();
    }
}

public interface IDbContextOptionsFactory
{
    DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> Get();
}

public class DbContextOptionsFactory : IDbContextOptionsFactory
{
    public DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                            .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                                            .Build();

            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();

            if (EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.Request.QueryString.ToString().ToLower().Contains("app1"))
                DbContextConfigurer.Configure(builder, configuration.GetConnectionString("app1"));
            else if (EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.Request.QueryString.ToString().ToLower().Contains("app2"))
                DbContextConfigurer.Configure(builder, configuration.GetConnectionString("app2"));

            return builder.Options;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public class DbContextConfigurer
{
    public static void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext> builder, string connectionString)
    {
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
}
```

**AppDbContext:**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        Assembly assemblyWithConfigurations = typeof(IDbContext).Assembly;
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(assemblyWithConfigurations);
    }

    //..
    //..
}
```

During runtime, I am getting below error.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'AppDbContext' can be invoked with the available
>   services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[AppDbContext]
>   options' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[AppDbContext])'.
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetValidConstructorBindings(ConstructorInfo[]
>   availableConstructors, IComponentContext context,
>   IEnumerable parameters)

I have tried as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836172/4337436)..but, not working.

Comment: Have you tried just to register options? `builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IDbContextOptionsFactory>().Get());` ?

Comment: @GuruStron when I add your code above `builder.RegisterType<AppDbContext>()...` I got this error. `InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.`

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks! :) It worked with little modification in the code. I have posted that as answer. As per your comment and my understanding, `builder.Register()` used when register a delegate as a component. if do so, `Autofac` resolve that delegate in `ComponentContext`. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by doing change as Guru Stron's comment and subsequent changes. Here is my change.

**Step 1:** Changed Autofac Registration class as below:

```
public class DependencyRegistrar : IDependencyRegistrar
{
    public virtual void Register(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //Removed this code
        //builder.RegisterType(typeof(DbContextOptionsFactory))
        //    .As(typeof(IDbContextOptionsFactory))
        //    .InstancePerRequest();

        //Added this code
        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IDbContextOptionsFactory>().Get())
            .InstancePerDependency();  // <-- Changed this line

        builder.RegisterType<AppDbContext>()
            .As(typeof(IDbContext))
            .WithParameter(
                new ResolvedParameter(
                    (pi, cc) => pi.Name == "options",
                    (pi, cc) => cc.Resolve<IDbContextOptionsFactory>().Get()))
            .InstancePerDependency();  // <-- Added this line

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
            .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
            .InstancePerDependency();  // <-- Changed this line
    }
}
```

Now, if you getting the error:

> InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured
>   for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the
>   DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the
>   application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also
>   ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions
>   object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for
>   DbContext.

By add below code in `AppDbContext` class to resolve above error.

**Step 2:** Modified `AppDbContext` (Added `OnConfiguring()` method)

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        Assembly assemblyWithConfigurations = typeof(IDbContext).Assembly;
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(assemblyWithConfigurations);
    }

    //Added this method
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder dbContextOptionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(dbContextOptionsBuilder);
    }

    //..
    //..
}
```