# Create Dbcontext at run-time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I have a requirement to switch to a different data sources at runtime. sometimes user wants to connect to a different database server to manipulate data. There can be more than 100 client servers with an identical database. Original project is a .net core Web API and the server name is an input parameter.

This is what I thought. Is there a better alternative?

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasKey(a => a.Id);

    }
}
class Program : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var _context = new Program().CreateDbContext();
            //transactions
            while (true)
            {
                var server_name = Console.ReadLine();
                if (server_name == "exit")
                    break;
                string[] remoteServer = { server_name };

                //new context
                using var dbContextRemote = new Program().CreateDbContext(remoteServer);

                try
                {
                    dbContextRemote.Database.BeginTransaction();

                    var result = await dbContextRemote.Persons.FindAsync(1);
                    //.....
                    //can be set of queries
                    Console.WriteLine(result?.Name);

                    // Commit transaction if all commands succeed, transaction will auto-rollback
                    dbContextRemote.Database.CommitTransaction();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    //dbContextRemote.Database.RollbackTransaction();
                    break;
                }
                _context.Database.CloseConnection();
            }

        }
        public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args = null)
        {
            if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
                args = new string[] { "localhost" };

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer($"Server={args[0]};Database=SampleDb;Trusted_Connection=True");
            return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what is the issue with this approach? I can easily create a wrapper around each database query and use it every time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are registering your DB with `AddDbContext` call you can leverage it's overload which provides you access to [`IServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions_AddDbContext__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action_System_IServiceProvider_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder__Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<MyContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
        {
             var connectionString = serviceProvider.GetService // get your service 
             // which can determine needed connection string based on your logic
             .GetConnectionString();
              options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
         });
       }
}
```

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61677516/autofac-resolvedparameter-using-reflection-componentcontext-not-working) something similar is achieved with Autofac.

Comment: OK.  I think in this way I need to register/configure all databases before-hand. but in my case, there can be a new database each week. and there is a separate API call to retrieve all the database server names (from the local database). providing that to each API call users can retrieve the data from different databases. and what is the benefit of registering databases beforehand? is there any performance benefit? is it really necessary inject it each time

Comment: No, you don't need to register it beforehand. You reuse same dbcontext class(cause structure of all database is the same) with different connections strings. You will need to implement provider for connection strings which can give one based on information in current scope(in my usecase I've fetched info from httpcontext) and that's all.

Comment: @Lakmal Benefit is that you are reusing your DI and work with it as natively as you can.